# Making responsive footer with images inside

Tags: html, css

I've trying to make responsive footer without to use bootstrap. Just css but something doesn't go right. Buttons in the footer are also images not text links.
The structure of the footer is

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><img src="images/button.png" width="221" height="61" id="Image26"></a> </li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="images/button.png" width="221" height="61" id="Image27"></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="images/button.png" width="221" height="61" id="Image25"></a> </li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="images/button.png" width="221" height="61" id="Image24"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Copyright &copy;  | all rights reserved.</p>
</div>
```

This is the css of the footer

```
#footer{
    background: url(../images/bg-footer.png) repeat-x center top;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-top: -45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position-x: -15px;
}

#footer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;
}  

#footer ul li {
   float: left;
   height: 60px;
   line-height: 60px;
   margin: 0 0 0 25px;
   width: 220px;
}

#footer ul li:first-child {
   margin: 0;
}

#footer ul li a {
   background: url(../images/bg-menu1.png) no-repeat 0 -70px;
   color: #2B0D05;
   display: block;
   font-family: 'PlayballRegular';
   font-size: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#footer ul li.current a, 
#footer ul li a:hover {
   background: url(../images/bg-menu1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
   font-family: PlayballRegular;
}

#footer p {
   margin: 80px 0 0;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

The result is that when I resize the window there are 3 buttons instead of 4 and `<p></p>` become invisible.

Here is the [JSFFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qm7pqu5r/3/) of what I'm tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#footer ul li a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  /* height: auto; */ // may b this thing makes the change for this resolution.
 }
```

try after changing this css media query selector part may this thing will help to you.

now here is the change for your `<p>` tag

```
#footer p {
  margin: 80px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: white; // to show white colored text only.
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#footer {
  /* max-height: 0; */   // this thing was causing for <p> tag that was not showing
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm6W-Dhy2DYzedY8Y9dXl7HypMH6IQoJxWG-VQ4igf4Dhep0yC0knRYOZX);
  width: 100%;
}
```

change above two changes where i changed that may help you what you need

Comment: This fix the issue with the number of the images. `<p>text</p>` is still not visible

Comment: just a minute  i just forget that so sry for that dude

Comment: Now this is fixed both issues. Thank you. I accept your answer. Just a side question did you saw on the JSFFIDLE demo how the first button is a more left aligned.. other 3 buttons are equal. What can be problem with this button?

Comment: @Stan this issue is from this one class **#footer ul li:first-child {
  /* margin: 0; */
}** just remove coz this **li:first-child {}** selector selects the first li (means your button) and overrides it's inherited margin so

Comment: I've tried this but when I remove `margin: 0;` there this affects the buttons in desktop(normal) version of the site.

Comment: I've put in the media `#footer ul li:first-child {  margin-left: 25px; }` in the mobile version css and seems to work.

Comment: but you can just only use this selector with your particular resolution's media query right.?

Comment: I made it. Thank's for your help again!

Comment: @stan you can upvote the answer if liked and had solution though you have selected as an answer

Comment: it's oky @Stan  you get your solutions that's the more important thing.